# Which way to write 7th or seventh, 19th or nineteenth, 27th or twenty-seventh, 127, etc

Tags: writing-style, numbers, style-manuals

I type reports for the federal government.  I need to know what to do about writing numbers such as 7th or seventh, 19th or nineteenth, 27th or twenty-seventh, 190th or one hundred twenty-seventh or one hundred and twenty seventh please.  I know that consistency is key, and I need to know if there is an actual rule or right way to write these numbers.  Thank you very much for you time and assistance!!

Comment: Get the style guide of the department or agency you are writing for.

Answer (score 1):

Different organisations have different rules for this sort of thing, but typically small numbers are written out and larger numbers are written as digits.

The threshold for this varies - two global companies I have worked for had one to six as words, then 7 onwards as digits.

If there is a writing guide where you work, you should follow that, otherwise I'd suggest doing something similar to those two.

Answer (score 1):

If you work for the federal government of the United States, your governing style guide (unless you have been told otherwise) is probably the [*U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual*](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/content-detail.html), which is available online in its entirety.

This manual provides guidelines on how to handle ordinal numbers at sections 12.10–12.13 and 12.19 of [chapter 12 ("Numerals")](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/html/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008-14.htm). The guidelines cover these aspects of ordinal number usage: when to spell out ordinal numbers and when to use a numeral with an *-st*, *-nd*, or *-th* ending (section 12.10); how to handle juxtaposed ordinals of less than 10 and 10 or greater in the same sentence or paragraph (section 12.11); how to handle juxtaposed ordinal and cardinal numbers of less than 10 and 10 or greater in the same sentence or paragraph (section 12.12); how to handle ordinals in street addresses (section 12.13); and how to handle ordinals in proper names (section 12.19).

Other style guides, inevitably, have other guidelines on these points. You will have to consult the one appropriate for your office if it differs from the *GPO Style Manual*, but the point of creating that manual was to standardize style decisions across all U.S. federal government publications.